# Preventing row iteration in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dictionary

I have converted the following file into a pandas df:

https://www.fca.org.uk/publication/data/position-limits-contract-names-vpc.xlsx

I have converted the relevant rows (for myself) into a dict. The dict is of the form `{principal: [spot, aggregate, set(product codes)]}`. I have used the following code to convert it into this dict:

```
ifeu_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, set()])


for (_, row) in df.iterrows():
        if row.loc["Venue MIC"] == "IFEU":
            ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][2].add(row.loc["Venue Product Codes"])
            if type(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]) == int:
                # no need for append as default is to create a dict
                ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][0] = row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]
                ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][1] = row.loc["Other month limit#"]
            if type(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]) == str:
                try:
                    val = int(str(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]).split()[0].replace(",", ""))
                    val_2 = int(str(row.loc["Other month limit#"]).split()[0].replace(",", ""))
                    ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][0] = val
                    ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][1] = val_2
                except ValueError:
                    pass
```

However, this is really inefficient and so i have been attempting to change the way i am creating this dictionary.

One attempt is as follows:

```
ifeu_dict_2 = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, set()])

ifeu_mask = df["Venue MIC"] == "IFEU"
ifeu_df = df.loc[ifeu_mask]
spot_mask_int = ifeu_df["Spot month single limit#"].apply(type) == int


def spot_transform(x):
    try:
        return int(str(x).split()[0].replace(",", ""))
    except ValueError:
        return


ifeu_df["Spot month single limit#"] = ifeu_df.loc[~spot_mask_int, "Spot month single limit#"].apply(spot_transform)
ifeu_df["Other month limit#"] = ifeu_df.loc[~spot_mask_int, "Other month limit#"].apply(spot_transform)
spot_mask_int = ifeu_df["Spot month single limit#"].apply(type) == int
```

and then trying:

```
temp_df = [~spot_mask_int, ["Principal Venue Product Code", "Spot month single limit#", "Other month limit#"]]
ifeu_dict_2[temp_df.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][0] = temp_df.loc["Spot month single limit#"]

# this gives me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

or:

```
ifeu_dict_2[ifeu_df.loc[spot_mask_int, "Principal Venue Product Code"]][2].add(ifeu_df.loc["Venue Product Codes"])
ifeu_dict_2[ifeu_df.loc[spot_mask_int, "Principal Venue Product Code"]][0] = ifeu_df.loc[spot_mask_int, "Spot month single limit#"]
ifeu_dict_2[ifeu_df.loc[spot_mask_int, "Principal Venue Product Code"]][1] = ifeu_df.loc[spot_mask_int, "Other month limit#"]

# this gives me TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Been stuck for quite a while and not sure how to proceed. Any help would be massively appreciated, whether it be an answer or helpful links! (For links, I am new to coding so examples help me best atm).

If you would like a df to play with:

```
Index(['Commodity Derivative Name\n(including associated contracts)',
       'Venue MIC', 'Name of Trading Venue', 'Venue Product Codes',
       'Principal Venue Product Code', 'Spot month single limit#',
       'Other month limit#', 'Conversion Factor', 'Unit of measurement',
       'Definition of spot month'],
      dtype='object')

    API2 Rotterdam Coal Average Price Options (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,RCA,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
 Gasoil Diff - Gasoil 50ppm FOB Rotterdam Barges vs Low Sulphur Gasoil 1st Line Future,IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,ULH,ULH,2500,2500,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
 Marine Fuel 0.5% FOB Rotterdam Barges (Platts) Future,IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,MF3,MF3,2500,2500,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal (supporting Cal 1x Options),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,ATC,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal (supporting Qtr 1x Options),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,ATQ,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Cal 1x Options (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,ATD,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Early (122 days) Single Expiry Option (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,RDE,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Early (214 days) Single Expiry Option (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,RDF,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Early (305 days) Single Expiry Option (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,RDG,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Futures,IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,ATW,ATW,5,550 (24.9%),38,800 (20.5%),nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Options (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,RCO,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
API2 Rotterdam Coal Qtr 1x Options (Futures Style Margin),IFEU,INTERCONTINENTAL EXCHANGE - ICE FUTURES EUROPE,ATH,ATW,Aggregated with Principal,Aggregated with Principal,nan,Lots,Calendar Month
```

An entry in the finished dictionary should look like:

```
ATW = [5550, 38800, {'ATH', 'ATC', 'RDF', 'ATQ', 'RCA', 'ATD', 'RCO', 'RDG', 'RDE', 'ATW'}]
```

Comment: What makes you say that this is inefficient and that you need to do it differently? Is it taking longer than your requirements dictate it can take to be useful?

Comment: @scign manager said so basically... he prefers I don't use interrows as each there are no dependencies between them. It does also take longer to do it like that in terms of how long it takes the script to run.

Comment: convert df to numpy array and iterate over it, you will have to prepare indices of columns that you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data I understand now. The data includes multiple codes for each product and you need to end up with a `dict` that has a single entry for each group of codes. Your way goes row by row but a more efficient way would be to use the `DataFrame.groupby` method and process each group in one go.

The following code should be more efficient than going row by row.

```
df_ifeu = df[df['Venue MIC ']=='IFEU']

ifeu_dict = {}
for principal,g in df_ifeu.groupby('Principal Venue Product Code'):
    # find where the product code is the same as the principal code
    pr = g['Venue Product Codes '] == principal
    # get the values for the principal
    spot_val = g.loc[pr, 'Spot month single limit#'].iloc[0]
    other_val = g.loc[pr, 'Other month limit#'].iloc[0]
    # get the codes
    codes = set(g['Venue Product Codes '])
    # add the product to the dict
    ifeu_dict[principal] = [spot_val, other_val, codes]

# confirm we have one dict entry per principal product code
assert(len(ifeu_dict)==df_ifeu['Principal Venue Product Code'].nunique())
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question, really appreciate it!!
Still kind of unsure as to the way to go but your answer looks like what I should be aiming toward. Filtering the data and then creating the dict/product from the filtered dataframe. Nearly finished my code (had to prioritise some other stuff rn) but will share what I have as well. I'm guessing timing how long the code takes to run may be the most appropriate testing mechanism?